# Deep RL for a custom problem

Tags: optimization, reinforcement-learning

I'm trying to use RL to optimize a game that I'm currently playing.

Below is the chart depicting all the items(boxes) that have to be created at varying capacities to complete a level.

[image]

The number in arrows depict the inputs for the for the item. Time is the time taken in minutes for also depicted as cycle time. init_coins depicts the coins used for the 1st item of the batch.

These items have to be crafted in different quantities with individual cycle times. They are crafted using coins and the unit price increases with time to craft remaining the same.

Hence my objective is to reduce the total lead time. My only control is the production rate / batch size of each of the items mentioned under further items.

The unit cost for each item increases as follows:

1st unit is crafted with say x + (x/2) * 0 coins

2nd unit will be crafted with x + (x/2) * 1 coins

3rd unit will be crafted with x + (x/2) * 2 coins

where x is the init_coins of each of the items

But the cycle time for a batch (production rate) of items remains the same. Say I craft a 10 unit batch (production rate) of needle, I have to make sure that 10 units of ribbon & 40 units of metal is available at the time of crafting. And the price of the batch (production rate) will be

10 x + (x/2) * (0 + 1 + 2 + ... + 9)

The time to craft the batch (production rate) is constant at y.

I want to create a policy such that the wait times of the higher order items is minimized along with the number of coins used.

Need help in creating this environment, running simulations and optimize with DRL.

PS: Please feel free to ask questions if anything is unclear.

---

```
What is x?
x is the cost in coins of 1st unit of any of the items. all items have different initial unit price.
we can craft or produce 100s or 1000s on unit under the same cycle time but that would cost us a huge number of coins with item inventory lying after the cycle time / production time of that item is over.

How does the order affect the number of coins used?
So the value increases as follows
1st unit is crafted with say x + (x/2) * 0 coins
2nd unit will be crafted with x + (x/2) * 1 coins
3rd unit will be crafted with x + (x/2) * 2 coins
```